# How to merge 2 rows by 2 foreign keys in SQL Workbench?

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

So I have a database wheree I have a double connection between 2 tables.
[image: How it looks on my er diagram]

And now I have to find which 2 people have sent the most messages between one another.

Which i did like so:

```
 create view temp as select Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,Uporabnik_idUporabnik2, count(Sporocilo.id) as 
 st_sporocil from Sporocilo group by Sporocilo.Uporabnik_idUporabnik1, 
 Sporocilo.Uporabnik_idUporabnik2; select * from temp;
```

The problem is that this only counts 1 way communication. So it will count how many messages user1 sent to user2 and how many messages user2 sent to user1 as 2 diffrent rows. 
[image: Example of how it looks]

So how can I merge rows where row1 fk1=row2 fk2 and row2 fk1=row1 fk2?

Comment: This question would be much easier to understand if the tables and column names where English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create view temp as
 select Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,Uporabnik_idUporabnik2,count(idSporocilo) as st_sporocil   
 FROM 
  ( SELECT Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,Uporabnik_idUporabnik2,idSporocilo from Sporocilo 
    UNION 
    SELECT Uporabnik_idUporabnik2,Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,idSporocilo from Sporocilo 
  ) t
WHERE Uporabnik_idUporabnik1 > Uporabnik_idUporabnik2
GROUP BY Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,Uporabnik_idUporabnik2
```

The UNION with the reverse will get you the number of 2 way messages. Because you will group both sender, receiver and receiver, sender.
The problem now would be that you will still get two rows. F.ex:

```
Uporabnik_idUporabnik1,Uporabnik_idUporabnik2,st_sporocil
1,10,4
10,1,4
```

In order to show only one row I added the filter `Uporabnik_idUporabnik1 > Uporabnik_idUporabnik2` this will show only the first row. Be careful because this will suppress self conversations (where the sender is the same as the receiver)

Comment: Thank you so much! But when I try to use this code I get an error because there are 2 FROM statements one after the other. Is this because im using mysql workbench?

Comment: So sorry, I had a typo in my answer, I updated it. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: Hi while the syntax error is gone, now the code has an error. Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Sporocilo.id' in 'field list'

Comment: edited once more. But you should have been able to catch these :) 
What is a bit confusing is that in your screenshot your column is called idSporocilo but in your query it seems it is called id. So the adjustment I made might not work

Comment: Yeah sorry in the er diagram its called idSporocilo,but after converting it to sql I switched all ids to just id as it was easier to type. So thats not where the problem lies. I will try to figure out where the problem is and then update my post. Thanks for all your help!